# Use Facebook Graph API get my Latest Post without having me login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've wanted to display my latest post on my facebook fan-page on my site. I've tried the Facebook Graph Api and successfully did it. BUt when I am logout now, it returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 190,
    "error_subcode": 467
  }
}
```

How can I solved it? since I'm just displaying the latest post on my web so if anyone will access my site they will be able to see my latest post in my facebook fan-page.

Comment: You may consider to use plugins which was not require user to login, for example Google fan page, http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fgoogle&width=310&height=500&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&border_color=%23335F9D&stream=true&header=true&appId=180802128639636

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a facebook app for that page. And I used the app id to get the latest post of that page. And it is now working, even though there is no login user and it does not expires.